# Rotating a square

Tags: python, arrays, list, rotation, square

so What I'm trying to build is a program where it takes a 3x3 square and rotate it given the instructions. For example, If I have 3x3 square

```
0 5 2   
7 8 4   
1 6 3
```

rotations are these

```
U 2
D 2
L 1
D 2
```

and I rotate it: Up on 2nd column

```
0   5   4   
7   8   3   
1   6   2
```

Down on 2nd

```
0   5   2   
7   8   4   
1   6   3
```

Left on 1st row- not sure its right but

```
0   5   2   
8   4   7   
1   6   3
```

Down on 2nd row

```
0 5 3
8 4 2
1 6 7
```

the final rotation should be

```
0 5 3
8 4 2
1 6 7
```

Below is my program, I've managed to run the file and produce a 3x3 but I don't know how to shift the square, If anyone can help that the highly appreciative by giving pointer on how I can start shifting.

```
def readfile(x):
    list=[]
    file= open(x)
    count=0
    maxcount=0
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if count<3:
            line=line.rstrip('\n').split(' ')
            x=[]
            for i in line:
                x.append(int(i))
            list.append(x)
            count+=1
        elif count==3:
            maxcount=int(line.rstrip('\n'))
            for i in range(count):
                for j in range(count):
                    print(list[i][j],' ',end=' ')
                print()
            print(maxcount)
            count+=1
        elif maxcount>0:
            line=line.rstrip('\n')
            lines=line.split(' ')
            print(" ".join(lines))
            maxcount-=1
readfile("file.txt")
```

Comment: If you don't mind importing numpy package, I think `np.roll()` might work.

Comment: Please fix the question's wording regarding rows. Some of the "rows" are actually columns. For instance, columns rotate up/down, rows rotate left/right. Also note that the code provided doesn't terminate.
Don't name any variables "list" it is the name of the builtin type `list` and will overwrite it. While unrelated to your problem, it can cause lots of problems in code.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Sorry about the "rows" and thanks for letting know about the variable list. I believe the code should terminate when you call the function read file and the file it self which is the square and the rotations

Comment: @j1-lee I'm not obligated to use any libraries

Comment: I think the rotations are wrong. `UP` and `DOWN` rotations of columns give the same output. I think it's supposed to be `UP` shift and `DOWN` shift

Comment: @AcidResin Yeah that is what I meant 

Answer (score 0):

I have defined two functions which perform those operations inplace.You can pass right=True or up=True and  there is an optional parameter by which rotate by n steps.

```
def rotate_row_elements(matrix, row,by, right=True):
    if right:
        for i in range(by):
            matrix[row] = [matrix[row].pop(), *matrix[row]]
    else:
        for i in range(by):
            matrix[row] = [*matrix[row][1:], matrix[row][0]]

def rotate_col_elements(matrix, col,by, down=True):
    if down:
        temp = [matrix[j][col] for j in range(len(matrix))]
        
        for i in range(by):
            temp = [temp.pop(), *temp]
            
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            matrix[j][col] = temp[j]
            
    else:
        
        temp = [matrix[j][col] for j in range(len(matrix))]
        for i in range(by):
            temp = temp[1:] + [temp[0]]
        
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            matrix[j][col] = temp[j]        


matrix = [
    
[0 ,5, 2],   
[7 ,8 ,4  ] ,
[1, 6, 3 ]]
rotate_col_elements(matrix, 1, 2)
print(matrix)
```

[[0, 8, 2], [7, 6, 4], [1, 5, 3]]